# PHP string to integer question

Tags: php, string, integer

Quick question:

I have strings in the form of '121', '9998', etc. They are literally numbers surrounded by the single quotes.

How can I remove these quotes and cast them as integers? I'm passing to another program that needs them to be integers.

Thanks.

Comment: As you can see from various responses, you should clarify if the single quote is part of the string. i.e. Do you mean $str = '123', or do you mean $str = "'123'"?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this, but the most common are:

```
$int = intval($string);
```

Or, my preference:

```
$int = (int)$string;
```

Since `$string` has a literal single quote, you can [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) it first by taking advantage of its second parameter.

```
$int = (int)trim($string, "'");
```

Remember that [PHP is a weak typed, dynamic language](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php).

Comment: "They are literally numbers surrounded by the single quotes."

Comment: casting is better than intval in term of speed

Comment: @Tarek: even though you're literally right, it doesn't make sense until you have less than millions of castings

Answer (score 4):

Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$n = intval(trim($str, "'"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$int = (int)trim("'121'", "'");
```